# How to enable Accessibility service in Android management api (Work profile )?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility, android-management-api

I recently developed an app with **Android Management API**. This app has **Accessibility service** `MyAccessibilityService`.

I granted accessibility service permission from  **enterprise policy** from [enterprises.policies](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies) as

```
{
....
"permittedAccessibilityServices": {
"packageNames": [
"com.trackify.management.access.MyAccessibilityService",
]
}
....
}
```

From this doc

*Specifies permitted accessibility services. If the field is not set, any accessibility service can be used. If the field is set, only the accessibility services in this list and the system's built-in accessibility service can be used. In particular, if the field is set to empty, only the system's built-in accessibility servicess can be used.*

When i check app in work profile , app has not auto granted the accessibility permission and navigate to accessibility setting page  where i can't find any downloaded services of my package name.

This app works on personal profile.

I think this accessibility permission should be automatically granted when i mentioned **permittedAccessibilityServices** object in enterprise policy.

Again i tried on both work and personal profile, Now i can't do enable accessibility and it's disable by default . when i try to enable it shows dialog with

> can't enable . please contact your admin

Can someone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

For devices running on work profile mode, the app needs to be installed in the personal profile to be able to use it.

There is an open feature request with the Android team to remove the requirement to have the app installed in the primary profile in order to be able to grant accessibility services but there’s no timeline for if, or when, that will be implemented.

Comment: Hey Kevin, can you please share the feature request link that you mentioned above? I'd like to track it for our project too