# Configure Intune to enable an Android Accessibility app

Tags: android, accessibility, intune

We have an Android Accessibility Service app that can be deployed via for example Microsoft Intune.
In order for the Accessibility Service app to do it's job, it needs to be enabled in Android's Accessibility Settings:
[image]

Is it possible to enable it automatically via Intune?

Answer (score 0):

shortly: nope

you can't start `AccessibilityService` by own, either toggle this switch programmatically. Security reasons ofc - accessibility services have pretty big possibilites (e.g. faking touches, intercepting keyboard) and is highly unwelcome that any app could do that without user agreement and/or interaction. Most of them would be just tracking users not respecting privacy at all

edit: just found you are using Microsoft Intune, looks like its just another MDM system. sadly don't have idea if provide such feature, but looks like from Android side [there is a possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449249/how-to-enable-accessibility-service-in-android-management-api-work-profile) for enabling `AccessibilityService` from MDM side

Comment: I'm aware that it is not possible to enable Accessibility Services programmatically. 

When we talk Intune (yes an MDM solution), it's about managed devices.

Android is not only about your phone but there's a lot of Android appliances, displays, scanners, non-personal devices etc. where an organization needs to control all aspects of a device. And in this context, it is important that you can deploy and configure Android with all it's apps without manual user interaction in remote sites from users who doesn't have a clue.

Comment: I think this link is about how to specified permitted Accessibility Services - not whether they should be enabled or not.